# deploy Laravel and flutter web on the same app on heroku

Tags: laravel, deployment, flutter-web

I deploy laravel project and database to heroku and it works well,
then I have a flutter web to deploy on the same app in heroku
what should I do ?

I try this **git push heroku master --force** after i detect the app on heroku
but it doesn't work

note :I deploy the flutter web on heroku on another app name on heroku and it works
but I want the laravel and the flutter web on the same app on heroku
can any one advise me to deploy this on the same app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer it cannot to deploy both on the same server on heroku

because each one have to one server in order to work fine

if the backend integrated with the front for example **laravel+vue**
it is work on one server because its integrated in one project